# how can I use '#' instead of '?' with mod_rewrite

Tags: mod-rewrite

I use js on my website to load pages without reloading the layout. Because of the possibility of sharing the links on facebook, I had to show the params as a hash (i cant give the params as query string, otherwise the page will be reloaded). How can i rewrite `mywebsite.com/#query=string` to `mywebsite.com/?query=string`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't, since the URL fragment is never sent to the server. You will need to use XHR to load the appropriate content from the server.

Answer (score 2):

Your server will never see the hash part, browsers don't send that as part of HTTP request, so no way you'd do that with mod_rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to all saying earlier :

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var url = window.location.href ;           
        var pos = url.indexOf('#');
        if(pos!=-1){
            var addition = url.substring(pos);
            alert(addition);
            //do ajax request with 'addition' parameter value
        }
    </script>
```